# MobileFirst - Invoking Java SQL Adapter adapter procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am following the [Java SQL Adapter](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/java-adapter/java-sql-adapter/comment-page-1/) tutorial for MobileFirst Platform 7.

I'm trying to Get User with userId = "bjones", but I don't know how to set the params `{userId}` into the procedure `/adapters/UserAdapter/{userId}`.

```
function loadUsers(){
  busyIndicator.show();

  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/UserAdapter/", WLResourceRequest.GET);
  resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("userId", "bjones");
  resourceRequest.send().then(
        loadUsersSuccess,
        loadUsersFailure
);}

function loadUsersSuccess(result){
  WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");
  busyIndicator.hide();
  WL.Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(result));
  if (result.responseJSON.length>0) 
    displayFeeds(result.responseJSON);
  else 
    loadUsersFailure();}

function loadUsersFailure(result){
  WL.Logger.error("Feed retrieve failure");
  busyIndicator.hide();
  WL.SimpleDialog.show("Banking Application", "Service not available. Try again later.", 
        [{
            text : 'Reload',
            handler : WL.Client.reloadApp 
        },
        {
            text: 'Close',
            handler : function() {}
        }]
    );}
```

My request is

> localhost:10080/JavaAdapters/adapters/UserAdapter/?userId=bjones

but the JSON response contains all user stored in my database
[Image for response](https://www.dropbox.com/s/scz94brw2kdz5a9/json.jpg?dl=1)

In addition, how about the REST call type `@PUT`, with Path param "userId" and body params: "firstName", "lastName", "password", in order to update an user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tutorial the adapter endpoint is `/{userId}` which means the `userId` is not a query param but it is part of the url. You need to update your `loadUsers` function so that it appends the `userId` at the end of the url, so in your example the fullpath will be `/adapters/UserAdapter/bjones`

```
function loadUsers(){
  busyIndicator.show();

  var usedId = "bjones";

  var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/UserAdapter/"+userId, WLResourceRequest.GET);
  resourceRequest.send().then(loadUsersSuccess,loadUsersFailure);

}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
function loadUsersSuccess(result) {
  WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");
  busyIndicator.hide();
  WL.Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(result));
  // if responseJSON is not null user data was returned
  if (result.responseJSON != null) {
    displayFeeds(result.responseJSON);
  } else{
    loadUsersFailure();
  }
}
```

Comment: how to define loadUsersSuccess function, because now result.responseJSON.length is undefined. "responseJSON":{"lastName":"Jones","userId":"bjones","firstName":"Brad","password":"bjones"}

Comment: check the update to the answer. there are many other ways you could do that

Answer (score 1):

there are basically two type of URL with Parameters: 
1. Path parameter:
 /adapters/UserAdapter/users/{userId}
2. Query Parameter:
 /adapters/UserAdapter/users?userId={userId}

java adapter with query parameter:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = false)
@Path("/users")

public String getuserById(@QueryParam("userID") String userId)

{
           System.out.println(userId);
}
```

java adapter with path parameter:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@OAuthSecurity(enabled = false)
@Path("/users/{userId}")

public String getuserById(@PathParam("userId") String userId)

{
           System.out.println(userId);
}
```

I hope, second example answers your question in java adapter.